# How is called the feature that let's ruby execute code inside classes while interpreting the file

Tags: ruby

When I have the following ruby code

```rb
#file a.rb
class A
   puts '2'
end
```

if I execute `rb a.rb` I get `2` printed onto the screen. This is because of the way ruby interprets the code, but, what is the name of this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it prints something is because in the course of defining class `A` you asked it to. Anything inside a `class` block is treated as regular Ruby code, it's not special, so printing, exiting, making network connections, opening files, that all works as it would anywhere else.

This is in stark contrast to things like JavaScript and C++ where that is absolutely not allowed.

Ruby, being a dynamic programming language, has a lot more latitude. This permits things like defining methods based on input from files, or pretty much anything you can imagine.

The name of this behaviour is basically "evaluation", as in when Ruby *evaluates* that code, that is it parses and runs it.

This allows you to do things in Ruby not possible in other languages without employing macros, pre-processor tricks, or other techniques:

```
class A
  if (Date.today.saturday? or Date.today.sunday?)
    def party!
      :on
    end
  end
end
```

Where that will only define the `party!` method when the code is run on a weekend.

Comment: Another example: `class G; def self.g; puts "hi"; end; g; def h; end; end` displays `"hi"` and then returns `:h`. Even better: `class B; def b; puts "hi"; end; new.b; end` displays `"hi"` and then returns `nil`.